# How would i go about plotting this in matlab

Tags: matlab

So I have this matrix `A = [1.9, 0.025; 0.1, 1.225];`
And I want to multiply it with the vector `v = [1;0];`

I want to plot the sum of it up to 25 iteration, so I have a `for` loop and I use the sum function like this:

```
iter = 25;
v = [1;0];

for k = 1:iter
    s(k) = sum(A^k*v);
    hold on
    plot(k,s(k))
end
```

But the plot shows up empty, how would I go about doing this?
This is for general understanding of plots with matrices and arrays and for loops, not really a school assignment.

Comment: What is A? You haven't defined it. If you do, it should plot the points.

Comment: You are raising to the 25th power every time.  Should that be sum(A^k*v)

Comment: Now it is correct. I wanted to raise it by the amount of iteration and plot the resulting sum against the iteration k.

Answer (score 0):

you are multiplying a 2*2 Matrix A with a 2*1 vector and then you are summing up the values of the resulting vector, so you have a scalar.

What do you expect to see when you plot a single Point? A BIG DOT? then you must wait Long..

Answer (score 0):

It is corrected now

```
iter = 25;  
v = [1;0];

for k = 1:iter

  s(k) = sum(A^k*v);
  hold on
  plot(k,s(k))
end
```

Like this, but still no valid plot.

Comment: plot(1:iter,s(1:iter))

Answer (score 0):

Because you are plotting points, you don't see something. If you add something like `'o'` to the `plot` command (e.g., `plot(k,s(k),'o')`), you should see something.

BTW, generally speaking, it would be better to do the plot outside the loop, e.g.:

```
iter = 25;  
v = [1; 0];
A = [1.9, 0.025; 0.1, 1.225];

s = zeros(25, 1); % Initialize vector to prevent growing vector inside loop
for k = 1:iter
    v = A*v;
    s(k) = sum(v);
end
plot(s, '-o')
```

[image: Plot generated by the matlab code]